# The four great elements and scientific equivalent

Tags: science, academic-buddhism

Science categorize physical world in to solid,liquid,gas and energy(thermal,kinetic,nuclear,radiation etc....) when it analyze, prove that nothing more than those three state of material and energy and science has already proven the interconnection of energy and matter(in nuclear technology). Also the three state of matter is conditioned by energy.E.g when you apply heat(energy) to ice (solid) it will convert into water(liquid) and further reach steam(gas). Once we consider four great elements patavi,apo,thejo,vayo; is it an equivalent of above scientific categorization?

Comment: There are several other topics about the four elements: https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/search?q=four+elements+is%3Aquestion

Comment: Off topic for Buddhism, looks more like a Vedas / Hinduism question?

Comment: Those four elements you mentioned, it's not scientific categorization but more like to Hinduism or vedic...

Comment: This is not a question about Buddhism, but rather an ill-defined question about metaphysics and physics.

Comment: @YesheTenley I think it's asking whether the "[four great elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mah%C4%81bh%C5%ABta#Buddhism)" in Buddhism refer to the three states of matter plus energy, IOW it's a question about the meaning of terms used in Buddhist doctrine.

Answer (score 0):

Earth,water,fire and air . These elements are also conditioned to energy. they can also change states on application of energy. A huge planet composed of all above elements in all forms reduces to no matter state when becoming black hole.How could we explain that? our science is still collecting admission form to get it admitted in nursery. Buddha few days prior to his nirvana ,while walking with disciples, suddenly stopped and bending down picked a fistful of soil from the ground and said 'If you consider that i have attained some thing then this is worth of this fistful of soil against the quantum of unknown which is whole of the soil of this earth". so enjoy.

Comment: That's alchemy, not science. No scientist pretends to know exactly [what happens to matter](https://www.nature.com/scitable/blog/thebeyond/what_happens_to_matter_inside) when it passes the event horizon of a black hole.